# St. Petersburg and Leningrad Region evisa

Tags: russia, eu-citizens, e-visas

I am a EU citizen planning to travel to the Baltic republics this summer and was wondering if I can visit St Petersburg too (I found multiple companies offering bus services between Tallin and St Petersburg).
The website https://www.e-visa-russia.com/st-petersburg seems active, stating

> In order to ensure state security, to protect public health and not to spread the new coronavirus infection in the Russian Federation, from March 18, 2020 to May 31, 2020 the issuance of electronic visas for visiting the Far Eastern Federal District, Kaliningrad Oblast, Saint‑Petersburg and Leningrad Oblast has been suspended.

Could anyone in the community please confirm if it's possible to obtain a St Petersburg e-visa ? I am aware Russia scrapped the unified e-visa :https://electronic-visa.kdmid.ru/index_en.html.

Comment: This may not be the best time to travel to Russia. Make sure that you understand what you are getting yourself into and what the moral/ethical considerations are.

Comment: The advice of the Dutch government is to only travel to Russia if strictly necessary. I suppose other EU members will have similar advices.

Comment: @Hilmar in terms of actual, physical safety on the ground it's no more dangerous than pre-war travel. Moral/ethical considerations may still exist, of course, and can be taken into account.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike It is more than just moral/ethical considerations that need to be taken into account.  There are potential monetary issues with bank sanctions (which likely means foreigners carrying cash - making them a bigger target for robbery).  Then there is the reduced ability of accessing consular services if something does happen to you. And finally, I don't know how much anti-western sentiment there currently is there, but I would expect it to be higher than pre-war.

Comment: Also one should double check any exclusions on travel insurance policies.

Comment: Or they might arrest you, so they can exchange you for a prisoner of their choice....

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have no idea if foreign tourists can open bank accounts in Russia.  But if they could, how do you think that they import the currency needed to do so, given the embargos on the Russian banking system?  I'm sure that there are sketchy means of transferring money, but .. sketchy.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Which are also subject to embargo.  For example, see [here](https://home.treasury.gov/news/press-releases/jy0608)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sure the embargo has gaps, but what protections do you have using those gaps?  Also, everything I have now seen about opening a bank account in Russia implies that you need a residency permit.  Something a tourist won't have.  Which brings us back to tourists carrying cash.

Comment: @Marianne013, you mean, in case you do something illegal?

Comment: @mintay - something illegal, such as carrying small amounts of narcotics that are legal in the country you are coming from, then being sentenced to nine years in prison and finally exchanged for a notorious arms dealer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Bout%E2%80%93Brittney_Griner_prisoner_exchange

Comment: @rob74, afaik bringing narcotics is illegal in most countries and can lead to arrests. The initial comment made it seem like this may happen without any reason...

Comment: @PeterM even 5 years ago it wasn’t uncommon for tourists to carry large sums of money with them into foreign countries to avoid bank fees or because they didn’t trust their card to work in a foreign ATM. It’s not that big of a deal - and I don’t remember Travel.SE advising people not to travel to places that have poor card acceptance.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike I'm not advising anything.  What I am doing is pointing out is that post-bank embargo tourists will *have* to be carrying cash, and that IMHO the situation there likely increases the personal risk to tourists for several reasons (political and economic).

Comment: @PeterM my contention is that the risks are still not that different from what they were in 2013, before the conflict began. Is Moscow more dangerous than Tokyo? Yes. But this isn’t because of the war.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Russian Ministry of International Affairs just issued [news piece](https://www.mid.ru/ru/foreign_policy/news/1897895/) that e-visas will make a comeback starting from August 1, 2023.

> From August 1, 2023, a practical launch of the system for issuing unified electronic visas to foreign citizens valid throughout the territory of the Russian Federation will be carried out. At the same time, the list of foreign countries whose citizens are issued such a visa will be preserved and expanded, which currently includes 52 countries.

That makes it a "yes", though the [web site of e-visa](https://electronic-visa.kdmid.ru) <s>still does not work</s>.

Update Sep 2023: The website is now live, and it promises that:

> FAST
> An e-visa is issued within 4 calendar days, including week-ends and bank holidays.

> EASY
> There is no need for any invitations or confirmations. Just fill in the application form on the website.

> CONVENIENT
> There is no need to waste your free time or working hours to visit the consular agency during its business hours. The website works 24/7.

Looks like it would now be country-wide and not restricted to SPb region.

With regards to country list, as per 2023 there are most of **EU**, China, India, Indonesia, Japan, but **neither USA nor Canada**. Latin America, Thailand and South Korea are not on the list, but I believe they have visa waiver when travelling to Russia.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is still suspended .

The embassy of Russia in France [states](https://france.mid.ru/fr/consulats/visas/e-visa/) :

> POUR DES RAISONS SANITAIRES, LES VISAS ÉLECTRONIQUES NE SONT PAS DÉLIVRÉS.

> For sanitary reasons, electronic visas aren't supplied

The [link](https://electronic-visa.kdmid.ru/spb_home_en.html) given by the embassy for that visa kind now is a 404